# Getting the name with dashes using substring_index MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, substring

I have a data that have this result:

[image]

I'm using the query

```
select substring_index(descriptn, ' ', -1) from table1
```

and I get my result along with the dash for example "JACQ-ARMIE"

I want to get only **JACQ** and **ABBY**. Can you give me hints on how to get the name? Does this also apply for substring_index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `substring_index()` again:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(descriptn, ' ', -1), '-', 1)
from table1;
```

Comment: that did the trick :) Thank you. :) I didn't know you can use special characters when doing substring_index :)